# Does $\sum\frac{\sin n}{n!}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does $\sum\frac{\sin n}{n!}$ converge?

Because of n! I thought of the ratio test, but the sin(n) would be a problem. Any tips?

Comment: Your title and question body are different?

Comment: The denominator in the title is $n$ while it is $n!$ in the main body of the question.  Which is the one of interest here?

Comment: I rolled back to the original question to make clearer the OP has two different series in the title and in the body of the question.

Comment: Why the title is different? I'm going to change it.

Comment: @DonAntonio Clearly the OP is about the solved one, I've changed the title.

Comment: Yes, the one with n! is the right one. Sorry about that. Thank you, @gimusi.

Comment: @vairë You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

$$\left|\frac{\sin n}{n!}\right|\le\frac1{n!}$$

Comment: and $\frac1{n!}$ seems to be very prone to converge :)